# Notification when Spring starts a transaction?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I'd like to be notified when Spring *starts* a transaction. I'm aware of `org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager` but afaik you can only use it to get notified of the transaction phases that defined in `org.springframework.transaction.event.TransactionPhase` (`BEFORE_COMMIT`, `AFTER_COMPLETION`, `AFTER_COMMIT`, `AFTER_ROLLBACK`). But how can I get notified just before or after a transaction has started?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I want to generate a UUID for the transaction that is available only during lifetime of the transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overide org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager

```
@Override
protected void doBegin(Object transaction, TransactionDefinition definition) {
   //UUID code here
   super.doBegin(transaction, definition);
}
```